# Calendar application

Tags: windows, calendar

Does anyone know of a calendar server application which will run on a Windows Server allowing users to open and edit their calendars from Windows desktops using Mozilla Sunbird?

We also need to be able to open or sync the calendars to blackberrys.

We need to run a local server app rather than using Google Calendar for example and also we do not run Exchange.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've systematically described Google Calendars, and then excluded it from the solution. I'm not sure what else would fill that gap.

What mail server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Sunbird will work with [CalDAV compatible servers](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Calendar:QA_CalDAV_Support), from the list on that page it looks like [Zimbra also has support for Blackberry](http://www.zimbra.com/products/zimbra_mobile.html), in addition it looks like the [Sun Java System Calendar Server](http://www.sun.com/software/products/calendar_srvr/index.xml) will [sync with a Blackberry through an add-on](http://www.sun.com/software/products/calendar_srvr/previous/faq_stub.xml#q40).

Answer (score 0):

We used [a product called iCal](http://www.brownbearsw.com/) for a few years and liked it.  Lightweight, easy to use, but doesn't have the Blackberry sync that I missed when I first read your message.